# Nautilus doesn't remember sorting options

Tags: nautilus

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and am using the Gnome desktop with no effects. I guess it is Nautilus that I get when I click on Places from the menu. My problem is that if I save a file in a folder and later try to open it by sorting modified, Nautilus never remembers this state. Thus, I have to sort the files all over again. I wish I had left 10.04 LTS installed.